# Powershell ISE v5 Presentations.Open Method Password Protected

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I'm trying to automate opening and saving a lot of powerpoints that all have the same password. I have done this with excels already, the only point that is unclear is I couldn't find any information online about passing a password variable through presentation.open. I was able to do that with WorkBooks.open

The script looks like this"

```
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


$passwd = Read-Host("Type in the password:")
$objPP = new-object -comobject powerpoint.application
$objPP.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue

#Paste in Path to Powerpoints
dir C:\Users\me\Desktop\cracking\*.pptx | ForEach-Object {


$doc = $objPP.presentations.open($_.FullName)

}
```

I'm not sure how to configure the parameter of presentation.open to pass $passwd

When I did this with excel it basically looked like this:

```
$doc = $objExcel.WorkBooks.Open($_.FullName,1,$false,5,"$passwd","$passwd")
```

Is there a way to do this with powerpoint?

OR is there a way to focus in on the password box so I can use SENDKEYs?
That may also work and I may try to go that route to do this with PDFs.

The problem I noticed is once that password box comes up my script will not continue until after I type in the password. I can't SENDKEYs to the password box.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use `Get-Credential` as it's more secure than `Read-Host`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for opening a password-protected presentation in VBA, assuming you know the password, is:

```
Presentations.Open("c:\temp\open.pptx::password::")
```

IIRC, no error results if you use a password on a non-passworded file; passing the wrong password results in a trappable error, so you can use that to test for password protected files even when you don't know the password ... just pass a bogus password and test for errors.